# JavaScript issue with animating elements on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a slide in menu, which contains 3 elements (div's), idea is that each one on hover expands its width from 33% to 60, while at the same time other two shrink to 20%, therefore 100% is never exceeded.

**Two issues I am having right now:**

1. On fast mouse move from element 1 to element 3, screen starts to behave funny, as it flickers like hover on element 2 is being called (because mouse goes over element 2 to get to element3), and results in blank space and overflow for a second or two, until hover function on element 3 takes place.

   - I tried stopping this using timeout function, but it must not be a good solution, as it did not work
2. Once I hover off this container, the hover on element 1, which was the last hovered all the time, stays at 60%, and does not return. Not quite sure where to set this behavior. On hover of another element and then check, or mouseout, idk.

The code..

HTML

```
<div id="elem1" onmouseover="focusDiv('elem1')">
   <div style="position: relative; top: 50%; left: 0">E1</div>
</div>

<div id="elem2" onmouseover="focusDiv('elem2')">
   <div style="position: relative; top: 50%; right: 0">E2</div>
</div>

<div id="elem3" onmouseover="focusDiv('elem3')">
   <div style="position: relative; top: 50%; right: 0">E3</div>
</div>
```

JS function

```
function focusDiv(menuItem) {

var nameOne = 'elem1';
var nameTwo = 'elem2';
var nameThree = 'elem3';

if (menuItem == nameOne){
    var main = document.getElementById("elem1");
    var siblingOne = document.getElementById("elem2");
    var siblingTwo = document.getElementById("elem3");
} else if (menuItem == nameTwo){
    var main = document.getElementById("elem2");
    var siblingOne = document.getElementById("elem1");
    var siblingTwo = document.getElementById("elem3");
} else if (menuItem == nameThree){
    var main = document.getElementById("elem3");
    var siblingOne = document.getElementById("elem2");
    var siblingTwo = document.getElementById("elem1");
} else {
    console.log('Something wrong');
};

if(hoverActive || (siblingOne.style.width == "59%" || siblingTwo.style.width == "59%")){
    if(siblingOne.style.width == "59%"){

        siblingOne.style.WebkitAnimation = "return-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        siblingOne.style.animation = "return-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        siblingOne.style.width = "20%";

        main.style.WebkitAnimation = "expand-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        main.style.animation = "expand-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        main.style.width = "59%";

    } else if (siblingTwo.style.width == "59%"){

        siblingTwo.style.WebkitAnimation = "return-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        siblingTwo.style.animation = "return-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        siblingTwo.style.width = "20%";

        main.style.WebkitAnimation = "expand-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        main.style.animation = "expand-large-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
        main.style.width = "59%";

    }

} else {
    main.style.WebkitAnimation = "expand-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    main.style.animation = "expand-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    main.style.width = "59%";

    siblingOne.style.WebkitAnimation = "shrink-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    siblingOne.style.animation = "shrink-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    siblingOne.style.width = "20%";

    siblingTwo.style.WebkitAnimation = "shrink-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    siblingTwo.style.animation = "shrink-width 1s 1 ease-in-out";
    siblingTwo.style.width = "20%";
    hoverActive = true;
}
```

}

And the CSS animations

```
@keyframes expand-width {
    from { width: 33%;}
    to {width: 59%;}
}

@keyframes expand-large-width {
    from { width: 20%;}
    to {width: 59%;}
}

@keyframes shrink-width {
    from { width: 33%;}
    to {width: 20%;}
}

@keyframes return-width {
    from { width: 59%;}
    to {width: 33%;}
}

@keyframes return-large-width {
    from { width: 59%;}
    to {width: 20%;}
}
```

Comment: might be better if u use onmouseenter and onmouseleave ? Event is fired less times.

Comment: ok, will do it, but not sure it helps my issue

Comment: i hope it may solve first issue, not both, plus, easyer to toggle class *expanded* on mouse enter and mouse leave, and use css3- transitions

Comment: hm...ok, I will try it with timeout, so animations do not collide with one another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tryng to synchronize the different changes is quite difficult.

Much better to change the approach radically: use flex to autoadjust the non-hovered items

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
 }
.test {
  flex: 33% 1 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: flex-basis 1s 0.3s;
 }

.test:hover {
  flex-basis: 60%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
addClass = function(el){
  el.classList.add('expanded')
}
removeClass = function(el){
  el.classList.remove('expanded')
}
```

```css
#elem1,#elem2,#elem3{
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 50%;
  background:#ddd;
}
.expanded{
  width:90%!important;
  background:#999!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1"class="default" onmouseover="addClass(this)" onmouseout="removeClass(this)">
   <div>E1</div>
</div>

<div id="elem2"class="default" onmouseover="addClass(this)" onmouseout="removeClass(this)">
   <div>E2</div>
</div>

<div id="elem3" class="default" onmouseover="addClass(this)" onmouseout="removeClass(this)">
   <div>E3</div>
</div>
```